# C# thread safe static member

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, atomic

I have a C# class with a static member, that is read from multiple threads and written in one thread.

As far as I know Uint64 read and write is not an atomic operation on all systems, so I have to manually guarantee thread safety.

I had a few ideas about how to do this.

1. Do it with and atomic wrapper class, like std::atomic in c++. Is there something similar implemented in C#?
2. Use the volatile modifier with static field. However this is not allowed. Why?
3. I finally did the following:

   ```
   private static object tick_time_lock;
   private static UInt64 _currentTickTime;
   public static UInt64 CurrentTickTime 
   {
       get
       {
           return _currentTickTime;
       }
       set
       {
           lock (tick_time_lock)
           {
               _currentTickTime = value;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Is this the correct way of making this field thread-safe?

Comment: yes it is however remember that it will slow down when you have many threads setting. there will also be a race condition. for example, if you update the value to... 1, the next thread may update it to 2, but then the 4th may update it to... 4 and the 3rd may come in later due to some race condition and override the last up to date value. BTW, you need to new up the tick_time_lock object.

Comment: You might be looking for the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) utility class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this the correct way of making this field thread-safe?

A monitor lock is meaningless unless *all* accesses of a given resource are synchronized.  Putting a lock around the `set` accessor is rather useless unless you also lock on the `get` accessor.  As you say, reads and writes of `UInt64` values are not atomic on all platforms.  What happens if the field is read in the `get` accessor when only the first word has been written in the `set` accessor?  You'd get a torn read.

> Use the volatile modifier with static field. However this is not allowed. Why?

The C# language designers felt it was beneficial to guarantee that all `volatile` field accesses are atomic.  As a trade-off, you cannot declare any 64-bit field as `volatile`.  I do not know for certain *why* this decision was made.  Perhaps they wanted to avoid adding "hidden" overhead to some volatile read/write operations and instead require developers to depend on framework-level facilities like `Thread.Volatile[Read/Write](ref long)` for handling 64-bit values.

> Do it with and atomic wrapper class, like std::atomic in c++. Is there something similar implemented in C#?

Yes.  There are framework-level atomic operations exposed through the `System.Threading.Interlocked` class, including `Read`, `Exchange`, `CompareExchange`.

Answer (score 5):

Look at **[`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** class, it provides atomic operations for variables that are shared by multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

For 64-bit integers, you might also consider using members of the `Interlocked` class in the .NET framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, you are doing it completely wrong. Having lock on only read/write operations is not going to help you. For example, this code is not thread safe, even though both get and set might be guarded by locks:

```
var time = Clock.CurrentTickTime;
time += 1
Clock.CurrentTickTime = time
```

You would need to put lock all around this code to make it thread-safe.

Also, making all components of a system thread-safe is not going to guarantee the whole system is thread-safe. It will actually increase posibilities of deadlocks and makes debugging harder.

Simply said, you are approaching thread safety from completely wrong angle. First, forget about synchronizing global state. It is extremely hard to have both global state and thread safety. Instead, have all state thread-local and only synchronize this state at precisely defined points, where you can guarantee a thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to instantiate your lock object. Also, use the lock for `get` too.

```
private static Object tick_time_lock = new Object();
private static UInt64 _currentTickTime;
public static UInt64 CurrentTickTime 
{
    get
    {
        lock (tick_time_lock)
        {
            return _currentTickTime;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock (tick_time_lock)
        {
            _currentTickTime = value;
        }
    }
}
```