# What is the difference between data type in x86 and x64 when using parallel task

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, x86, 64-bit

```
    static long x;
    const int count = 1000000;

    static void ThreadProc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            x = 0;
            var result = x;
            if (result != 0 && result != -1)
                Console.WriteLine("Opps 1");

        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(new Action(ThreadProc));

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            x = -1;
            var result = x;
            if (result != 0 && result != -1)
                Console.WriteLine("Opps 2");
        }

        task.Wait();
    }
```

This program run correctly in x64 but show text in writeline in x86. The result var hold value is -4294967296 or 4294967296 and x is still 0 or -1. I'm not sure it is max/min or temp value. When I change

```
static long x;
```

to

```
static int x;
```

the problem has gone. 
I do know that we should lock x variable. But I want to know why the result variable get wrong value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [We need to lock a .NET Int32 when reading it in a multithreaded code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395232/we-need-to-lock-a-net-int32-when-reading-it-in-a-multithreaded-code).  Of particular interest: _[Without any memory barriers, the JIT could just cache the value in a register and assume it hadn't changed between reads. The point of a memory barrier is to either make sure something is really written to main memory, or really read from main memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395232/we-need-to-lock-a-net-int32-when-reading-it-in-a-multithreaded-code)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `-4294967296` decimal is `0xffffffff00000000` as a 64-bit hexadecimal. The value `-1` decimal is `0xffffffffffffffff` as a 64-bit hexadecimal. And of course the value `0` is `0x0000000000000000`. Note that the erroneous value you are seeing is half of a `-1` and half of a `0`.

In your 32-bit program, a `long` (which is 64 bits) is not written to atomically. Instead, it is written as two 32-bit pieces. Likewise, a 64-bit value isn't read atomically, but instead is read in two 32-bit pieces.

Some of the time, one thread of the code you've shown will get caught by the other thread mid-write. Either writing two `0x00000000` parts to the variable, or two `0xffffffff` parts (depending on which thread got caught). Either thread behaving non-atomically could result in this, but of course *both* threads are behaving non-atomically (writing and reading), so depending on where each thread is in their race, you could "blame" the problem on either.

When you switch the variable type to an `int`, you are changing the data size from 64 bits to 32 bits, which in an x86 program can be written and read atomically. Thus neither thread can be caught mid-write or mid-read.

See related discussion:
[C# thread safe static member](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205405/3538012)

Comment: Peter Duniho: I don't get the point when result has -4294967296 or 4294967296 and x = 0 or -1. It shows that x is completed assigned to 0 or -1 even I changed result to result1 and result2 in 2 threads. The output is the same. May you explain more about this?

Comment: Your threads are running concurrently. The `result` variable gets the torn value, but by the time you get a chance to examine the value of `x`, the write has been completed in the other thread, and so you see one of the expected values.